# fgetcsv() with html entities in csv string

Tags: php, csv, parsing, html-entities, html-encode

I parse CSV string and recieve wrong number of columns and i think its because of html entities like this %2C%20.

I recieve wrong number of columns and i think its because of html entities like this %2C%20.

Plese help me to parse CSV string with html entities correcrtly

```
        $file = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $csvString, 'r+');
        $fileOffers = [];

        while (($data = fgetcsv($file) ) !== FALSE ) {
            $fileOffers[] = $data;
        }
```

But in one row i have this URL
https://typhur.sjv.io/c/77612/1936847/18771?kw=%22valentines%20day%20gifts%2C%20valentines%20day%20gift%20for%20men%22&prodsku=AF03-DTC

Answer (score 1):

According to provided code, to parse CSV string, containing URL, using PHP, here is updated code:

```
$file = fopen('data://text/plain,' . urlencode($csvString), 'r+');
$fileOffers = [];
while (($data = fgetcsv($file) ) !== FALSE ) {
    $fileOffers[] = $data;
}
```

When the URL is decoded, the value "%2C" becomes comma value, that is, "," value. To implement required functionality, in provided code, this line of code:

```
$file = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $csvString, 'r+');
```

is replaced with this line of code:

```
$file = fopen('data://text/plain,' . urlencode($csvString), 'r+');
```

It can be checked, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that that `data://text/plain,` interpolation is interpreting the entities. @Jai's solution adds another layer of encoding to get around that, but I wouldn't expect that that will be the end of potential issues with this approach.

If you need to fake a multi-line CSV document you're better off using a temporary stream like `php://temp` or `php://memory`.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

```php
$file = fopen('php://temp', 'rwb');
fwrite($file, $csvString);
rewind($file);

while( ($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE ) {
    $fileOffers[] = $data;
}
```

And if you've got just a single line of CSV that needs to be processed there's always [`str_getcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv).